# vtable and polymorphism - offset of a function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

If I understand things correctly, a class definition imposes a certain order of the virtual functions in the vtable, and so a given function is known to be at a certain offset from the beginning of the table. However, I don't understand how that works with polymorphism.

```
class B1 {
  virtual void funcB1();
};

class B2 {
  virtual void funcB2() {}
};

class D : public B1, public B2 {
  virtual void funcB1() {}
  virtual void funcB2() {}
};

void main(...) {
  B1 *b1 = new D();
  B2 *b2 = new D();
  B1 *realB1 = new B1();
  B2 *realB2 = new B2();

  b1->funcB1();
  b2->funcB2();
  realB1->funcB1();
  realB2->funcB2();
}
```

How does the generated code know how to access funcB2 at different offsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compose a class from two base classes, each part is represented in the resultant class by a fully functioning block, complete with its own pointer to vtable. That is how the generated code knows what function to call: casting the pointer of `D` to `B1` and `B2` produces different pointers, so the generated code can use the same offset into the virtual table.

```
D *d = new D();
B1 *b1 = dynamic_cast<B1*>(d);
B2 *b2 = dynamic_cast<B2*>(d);
printf("%p %p %p", (void*)d, (void*)b1, (void*)b2);
```

This [produces the following output on ideone](http://ideone.com/URZAX7):

```
0x91c7008 0x91c7008 0x91c700c
```

Note how `D*` and `B1*` print the same value, while `B2*` prints a different value. When you call `b2->funcB2()`, the pointer `b2` already points to a different part of the `D` object, which points to a different vtable (the one that has the layout of `B2`), so the generated code does not need to do anything differently for `b2` vs `realB2` in your example.

Comment: How does the compiler know whether it's getting an actual B2 or a D when I call a function that accepts a B2*? Does it add runtime code to check that, and calculate the offset accordingly?

Comment: @Dorfl When the compiler sees you calling a function that takes `B2*`, it silently inserts a cast of `D*` to `B2*` at the point of the call, so that the pointer the function gets looks and behaves as if it were a pure pointer to `B2`.

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks!
Sorry I can't vote you up yet, but I don't have the required reputation.

Comment: By the way, I just want to make sure - when I cast from B2* back to D*, does it add the opposite offset to get back to where D's table should be?

Comment: @Dorfl That's an excellent question! The answer is "yes" ([here is a modified demo](http://ideone.com/aO4j5b)).

Comment: Thanks! (I am required to enter at least 15 characters.)

Answer (score 1):

Typically the `D` object will have *two* vtable pointers, one for each base class. It really can't be avoided, since it must contain an identical binary layout for each of the base classes. The compiler will insert pointer fixups whenever you cast from one type to another - if you print the pointer addresses after casting to each of the base classes, you'll see that they are different.